# An electric bulb is rated 220 V and 100 W. When it is operated on 110 V, the power consumed will be...?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-current

> An electric bulb is rated 220 V and 100 W. When it is operated on 110 V, the power consumed will be...?

In this numerical I have a doubt that why I can't use $ P=VI $ but we can use $ P=\frac{V^2}{R}$. I searched and found that  $ R $ will be constant why is $R$  constant? Please give an elaborate explanation.

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! Please take a minute to read our [guidelines for homework and exercise questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) as well as [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093). We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and we prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation. In its current form your question looks just about OK to me, but it is on the edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can't use $P=VI$ because you don't know whether $I$ is constant (and, in fact, it isn't).
- **IF** the resistive element is the same and its properties don't change with the change of voltage, then $R$ will be constant between the two situations, which is why you can use $P=V^2/R$.
- In real life, incandescent light bulbs do *not* obey Ohm's law, because as the current increases, the temperature increases, and this makes the resistance increase as well. As such, to make any predictions, you would need the [I-V curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current%E2%80%93voltage_characteristic) for that circuit element.

In general, if you are asked a simple numerical set-piece question on a homework sheet, or equivalent, and you're not given any details about its I-V Curve, then it is safe to assume that it is linear, i.e., that $R$ is constant.

Answer (score 0):

R wont be constant in real life . There will be environmental interaction ,etc . It is just simplified to make the problem such that it can be solved using basic physics.

Comment: If this is an incandescent then R will not be constant. Operating at 110V, the lower filament of the temperature will cause a lower resistance.